# ONVIF Replay shows that no frames captured

Tags: onvif, replay

I am currently achieving the replay in Onvif Profile G, but I have encountered a problem. When I was tring to achieve the Video replay ,I uesd GetReplayUri to get URI of video stream from camera,then used the udp to transfer the rtsp protocol for replay,but the RTP packet was sent normally (VLC can also read videos normally by using the uri), but the Onvif Test Tool shows  "no frames captured" on the ONVIF TEST TOOL .

I have conducted packet capturing and found that the video frame was sent before the audio frame, so I tried to turn off the audio encoding, but the result was still the same. I want to figure out what problem should be causing this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

OK,recently by querying the Replay Control Device Test Specification,The reason why captured no frame is that I didn‘t send valid RTP header without including replay header extension.Now the question is solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).